# How to invoke a modal from a controller in angularjs / ui-bootstrap?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap, angular-bootstrap

I am trying to display a modal (Note view) from a controller (Details controller). I have separate controllers tied to each view.
The Details view has a list of radio buttons and upon selecting a radio button, it needs to display a modal with some data and OK and Cancel buttons.
Also, I need to deselect the radio button which is selected in Details view when cancel button is clicked on the modal.
How can I wire up all this? I am trying the below code and I get internal server error upon calling note modal from Details controller. 
I copied some parts from my code to show what I am trying.
Thanks for any suggestions.

**Details view:**

```
<div class="list-group-item" ng-repeat="cpo in details.detailoptions">
    <div class="row">
        <h4><input type="radio" name="optRadio" ng-model="$parent.selectedOption" 
                   ng-value="{{o}}" ng-change="optionSelected()" 
                   ng-disabled="disableOptions" /></h4>
    </div>      
</div>
```

**Details controller:**

```
appControllers.controller('detailsCtrl', ['$scope', '$uibModal',
    function ($scope, $uibModal) {

        $scope.selectedOption;

        $scope.optionSelected = function () {
            //call note modal
            $uibModal.open({
                templateUrl: 'notePanel',
                controller: 'noteCtrl',
                scope: $scope
            });
        }
    }
]);
```

**Note view:**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="notePanel" ng-controller="noteCtrl">
    <div id="noteModal" class="modal fade">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
                        <h4>{{Note.Note1}}</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-1 col-md-10">
                        {{Note.Note2}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                <div class="row row-centered">
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-thin col-centered">
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="OK()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span> Agree</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-3 col-thin col-centered">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-block" ng-click="Cancel()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Disagree</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</script>
```

**Note controller:**

```
appControllers.controller('noteCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataService',
    function ($scope, service) {

        $scope.Note;

        $scope.OK = function () {
            //close modal
        }

        $scope.Cancel = function () {
           //deselect the option selected in Details view.
        }

        function init() {
            service.getNote($scope.optionSelected, function (data) {
                if (data) {
                    $scope.Note = data;
                }
                else {
                    console.log('Error getting note file');
                    //show error dialog
                }
            });
        }

        init();

    }
]);
```

Comment: I think you have to read the uibModal documentation. It looks different than you code example

Comment: Thank you. I figured it out by following the documentation closely.

Comment: probably it's good idea to post the answer in case if someone did it. the same way you did it.